# APEX - linking two report with SQL

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm trying to link 2 reports to achieve the same functionality as with a master form on 2 pages.

```
table: Student(id, name, address)
```

MainReport: an interactive report Displaying the ID by using SQL: select id from student;

Functionality: when the ID is selected, open the other report and display the name and address

SubReport: this is a report on an SQL statement. SQL is:

```
select name, address from student where id = :P24_id;
```

Go back to the main report, go to edit page, in the region, click on interactive report and go to the report attributes. Scroll down to link column, change link column to link to custom target, set the target page to the SubReport, enter name of P24_id and value of #id# and click apply changes.

Why is this not working? When I load the main report I'm seeing the data, when I click on an ID however and I go to the subReport, I'm seeing Error ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "P24_ID" in application "105".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define a page item on page 24 (which seems to be your target page) with the name P24_ID ?
You can not just set a value to some arbitrary variable name. You need to actually have a page item matching the name. 
So on page 24 you would need to create a page item P24_ID.

Comment: I created a textfield on that page named p24_id and it's working now, thanks